# What is the cheapest option to connect a VGA monitor to a PC whose VGA port is broken?

Tags: display, motherboard, desktop-computer, vga, pci

I have got an Asus [A7V266-MX](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ASUS/A7V266-MX.html) motherboard, AMD PC desktop.
It was in running condition but recently the display stopped coming up.
Some investigation (including from local repair shop) confirmed that "its only VGA" port might have got disconnected/desoldered from somewhere inside (confirmed from fact that the vga port at back is moving a bit)

I want to get my display working again, what is best but also cheapest option?

Few options I thought about:

1. USB to VGA (not sure it will work, PC has got USB 2.0 slots)
2. PCI to VGA (not sure how to find a compatible one)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This motherboard is ancient. Have you considered replacing the computer altogether? Also what do you mean by "VGA slot"?

Comment: I assume you mean the VGA port has become desoldered from the motherboard.  The cheapest solution is for a different store, one that knows what they are doing, to repair the board (or at least try to repair it).

Comment: Is USB to VGA an option?     https://www.amazon.com/BENFEI-USB-Adapter-Male-Female/dp/B085KX97QG/

Comment: Can you use HDMI?